# How does Flash Builder determine which sdk libraries to include?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

When creating a new project in Flash Builder, how does it determine which sdk libraries to include in the build path?

If I create a new plain **Actionscript** project and select Flex **4.1** the following libraries show up in the build path:

- playerglobal
- textLayout
- osmf
- flash-integration
- flex
- utilities

If I go back and switch to Flex **3.5** it only includes:

- playerglobal
- flex
- utilities

If I make a new **Flex Web** project and select Flex **3.5** it includes:

- playerglobal
- framework
- automation
- automation_agent
- automation_dmv
- automation_flashflexkit
- datavisualization
- qtp
- rpc
- utilities

Are these values hardcoded in Flash Builder or is it somehow reading them from the SDK config files? I looked through all the xml config files like flex-config.xml and air-config.xml and it doesn't look like this information exists anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and some inspection with a decompiler I have the answer:

1. Flash Builder loads either the flex-config.xml or air-config.xml file (depending on the project type) from the sdk frameworks directory.
2. It goes through each entry listed in `library-path` and `library-external-path` adds it to the classpath if it is a SWC. If the entry is a directory it scans that directory for SWCs and includes them.
3. Each project type has a hardcoded list of exclusions which tell Flash Builder which SWCs to leave out of the classpath. For a plain actionscript project this list has 17 items. For a Flex Web project the list consists only of `flex.swc`. This list of exclusions is written to the `.actionScriptProperties` file.
4. Any remaining (not excluded) SWCs are automatically added to the classpath. No entry is necessary in the `.actionScriptProperties` file. (i.e. You can throw any file with a .swc extension in the frameworks/libs directory and Flash Builder will include it.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's built into the framework swc's.  You can find the references and where they're linked in under the /frameworks/build.xml file in your framework directory.

So you could edit this build file, rebuild the swcs and then use those and they'll link how you like.

For example, (from Flex 4.5.1 build file)  :

```
  <target name="authoringsupport" description="Builds authoringsupport.swc">
<compc static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="true" fork="true" output="${basedir}/libs/authoringsupport.swc" include-classes="AuthoringSupportClasses" locale="" accessible="true">
  <source-path path-element="${authoringsupport.dir}/src"/>
  <library-path dir="${authoringsupport.dir}/libs"><include name="FlexContentHolderThumbnail.swc"/></library-path>
  <external-library-path dir="${basedir}/libs">
      <include name="player/${playerglobal.version}/playerglobal.swc"/>
      <include name="framework.swc"/><include name="mx/mx.swc"/>
      <include name="flash-integration.swc"/>
      <include name="textLayout.swc"/>
  </external-library-path>
  <jvmarg line="${compc.jvm.args}"/>
</compc>
```

So its not technically hardcoded into flash builder, but in the swc's for that sdk. (but you can change that as noted above).   :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't seem to be correct either. I did a few hours of looking with a decompiler and some trial and error and it appears that the libraries *are* hardcoded in flash builder. It's a little more complicated than that though. I'll post an answer soon when I have a minute free.

Comment: When you start a project it points to the libraries via the .actionScriptProperties - but you can change that to point to your own - but you will need to build them yourself via the method I described.

Answer (score 2):

I created a Flex 4.1 project, and checked the flex-config of the Flex 4.1 SDK at the following location. I think this is where the included swc files in the Build Path are coming from - they matched for my project:

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.1.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml

[image]

Comment: That's where the RSL information comes from but nothing else. I removed those entries entirely and Flash Builder is now missing the RSL urls but all the SWCs still show up. Also, the flex-config.xml in 3.5 only has one entry for "framework".