# Missing skins in the output file?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The swc
> 'E:\DEV\Flash\Flex\SDK\4.14.1\frameworks\libs\advancedgrids.swc' has
> style defaults and is in the library-path, which means dependencies
> will be linked in without the styles.  This can cause applications,
> which use the output swc, to have missing skins.  The swc should be
> put in the external-library-path.
>
> SharedSledi       Unknown Flex Problem
> The swc 'E:\DEV\Flash\Flex\SDK\4.14.1\frameworks\libs\charts.swc' has
> style defaults and is in the library-path, which means dependencies
> will be linked in without the styles.  This can cause applications,
> which use the output swc, to have missing skins.  The swc should be
> put in the external-library-path.
>
> SharedSledi       Unknown Flex Problem
> The swc 'E:\DEV\Flash\Flex\SDK\4.14.1\frameworks\libs\framework.swc'
> has style defaults and is in the library-path, which means
> dependencies will be linked in without the styles.  This can cause
> applications, which use the output swc, to have missing skins.  The
> swc should be put in the
> external-library-path.
>
> SharedSledi        Unknown Flex Problem The swc
> 'E:\DEV\Flash\Flex\SDK\4.14.1\frameworks\libs\mx\mx.swc' has style
> defaults and is in the library-path, which means dependencies will be
> linked in without the styles.  This can cause applications, which use
> the output swc, to have missing skins.  The swc should be put in the
> external-library-path.
>
> SharedSledi       Unknown Flex Problem The swc
> 'E:\DEV\Flash\Flex\SDK\4.14.1\frameworks\libs\spark.swc' has style
> defaults and is in the library-path, which means dependencies will be
> linked in without the styles.  This can cause applications, which use
> the output swc, to have missing skins.  The swc should be put in the
> external-library-path.    SharedSledi     Unknown Flex Problem

- How to resolve this issue with the missing default skins ?

Comment: I have an internally-developed library that has the same issue.  Since I'm not exporting the library for anyone else to use, I just make sure the app I'm building that uses my lib does include the standard libraries with the skins defined.

Comment: When/How you get that error?

Comment: @YordanYanakiev... If my answer is not working for you, then respond so that alternative answers or suggestions can be given. Otherwise you will lose your rep points with still no accepted answer...

Comment: @VC.One It worked partially. After a lot of headbanging somehow it start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests : "The **swc** should be put in the **external-library-path**"

Check this official guide : **[Use Flex library projects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-1a92eab212e75b9d8b2-7ffe.html)**, specifically read this **[section link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-1a92eab212e75b9d8b2-7ffe.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-1a92eab212e75b9d8b2-7ff4)**. To quote :

**1) Add a SWC file to the library path**

> Add a SWC file to the library path
>
> 1. With a project selected in the `Package Explorer`, select `Project` > `Properties` > `Flex Build Path`.
> 2. Click the `Library Path` tab.
> 3. Select any of these options to add SWC files:
>
>    - **Add Project** Adds a Flex library project.
>    - **Add SWC Folder** Lets you add a folder that contains SWC files.
>    - **Add SWC** Adds a compiled SWC file.
>    - **Add Flex SDK** Lets you add other Flex SDKs. If your project already has a Flex SDK in its library path, this button is disabled.
>        If you remove the existing Flex SDK from your library path, the button
>        is enabled. When you click this button, a Flex SDK node is added, but
>        you are not prompted which one is added. To control which Flex SDK to
>        use, select `Project` > `Properties` > `Flex Compiler`.
> 4. Enter or browse to and select the location of the SWC file, project, or folder. Click OK. The SWC file, library project, or folder
>      is added to the library path.

**2) Set SWC as External Library...**

> Set the SWC file as an **external library file**
>
> 1. With a project selected in the `Package Explorer`, select `Project` > `Properties` > `Flex Build Path`.
> 2. Select the `Library Path` tab, and then select and expand the SWC file entry to display the SWC options.
> 3. Double-click the `Link Type` option. The `Library Path Items Options` dialog box appears
> 4. Select the `External` option, and click OK.
>
> This procedure is the equivalent of using the external-library-path
>   compiler option.

PS: This **[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6672267/2057709)** might have some clue for you, if you're willing to edit Flash Builder's XML files.